# wordpress get_the_content() function

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to know the following:

Is it possible to use `get_the_content` function to output in multiple places on the page?

For example:

`h3` tag `get_the_title()` -> here goes title, and that is ok

`p` tag > `get_the_content()` -> so here will be all content when admin adds them

So I don't want to output all at once, instead I want for example `p` 1 to be under the `h3` tag `p`2 to be under `img` tag or something...

How can I do that?

Just to show you:

```
h3
```

text of `p` 1 goes here

text of `p` 2 goes here (I would like to move it down)

```
img
```

text of `p`2 should be here and not above

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What you are suggesting is not using `get_the_content()` in multiple places, but to parse the returned content and split it into pieces. You can do this two ways:

1. On the PHP side using regular expressions
2. On the client side using JavaSCript + DOM

Both have drawbacks.

GETTING WITH `<p>` tags:

```
//We want to get it with paragraph tags, etc
$content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );
$content = str_replace( ']]>', ']]&gt;', $content );
```

With the PHP way, you'd then use regular expressions to separate everything by tags (**this is VERY complex**).

In JavaScript, you'd add script that does something like this:

```
var parent = document.getElementById( "contentDOM" );

//Get all the paragraphs
var paragraphs = parent.querySelectorAll( ".p" );

//Now move it to after the image
if ( myImage.nextSibling ) myImage.parentNode.insertBefore( paragraphs[ 1 ], myImage.nextSibling );
else myImage.parentNode.appendChild( paragraphs[ 1 ], myImage.nextSibling );
```

Comment: Ok, so the php is very complex and js will not work if user turn off javascript, right? What should I do then? Thank you

Comment: are you sure your site will even work without JavaScript? if it can be viewed without JavaScript, then do the php side version.

Comment: Ok I'm gonna try with php and regex

Comment: @StewieGriffin You could also look for a 3rd party library to use like: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ and pass it the HTML code to parse for you.

Comment: My basic idea is like this: `$content = get_the_content();` `$newContent = explode("</p>", $content);``foreach($newContent as $new){ // the rest }` but the problem now I'm facing is how to pass this result in specific class or id? for example `$new[0]` to be in div with id=one?

Comment: @StewieGriffin That's not the right way. you need everything between the `<p>...</p>` tags and there may be a paragraph inside a paragraph, etc. So try using that 3rd party link I posted in the previous comment.

Comment: Why do you think that there will be more p tags inside? Will check that link now. Thank you.

Comment: @StewieGriffin it depends on what the CMS user does in the content text box. they can format text in many ways

Answer (score 0):

Yes, yes it is possible to use `get_the_content()` in multiple places.